# Javascript for li tag onclick location

Tags: javascript

Javascript code for li tag onclick,

Am using below code but am not able to cover span tag onclick.

HTML:

```
<div class="primaryNav fl">

 <ul id="hd_vertical" class="productNav">

    <li id="info" class="validation">
    <span class="info">Test</span>
    <a class="info" href="http://validator.w3.org/">Test1</a>
    </li>

    <li id="learn" class="site">
    <span class="learn">fi</span>
    <a class="learn" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Buses</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

JS :

```
document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        var _anchor = e.target.id;
        var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(_anchor)[1].getAttribute('href');
        location.href = _url;
    }
});
```

jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/sudheera/NgwS5/

I have jquery code for li tag onclick,Am trying do same thing in Javascript.

please suggest me!!

Comment: what functionality do you want. Jsfiddle goes to the location on clicking.

Comment: But if you click on "Test" or "fi" (span tag) on click is not working

Comment: if you want that it should not go on nodeName other than LI then do `e.preventDefault()` case

Comment: e.target.nodeName for Buses is 'A' and for fi is 'SPAN' which is their html tag.

Comment: Just checked not working for SPAN

Comment: We can add onclick="info()" for li tag As per W3c? so i can add below code :                                                 function info()
  {
  window.location.assign("http://validator.w3.org/")
  }

Comment: Your event bubbles up - please [read more about event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). This way you will learn to understand the other comment.

Comment: Please suggest me if any other way I can do this?

Comment: You are on the right track. In this line `e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI"` you check if the source of your event was an `LI`. But if you click on the span-element the source is `span` and not `LI`. If you add `console.log(e.target)` and `console.log(e.target.nodeName)` in front of the if you will see.

Comment: This can be the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23674736/2260614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your check is written for `LI` only, it would not go inside the if statement for the other tags. You would have to handle the other also. so for `SPAN` tag you can do :

```
var changeLocation = function(id) {
  var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[1].getAttribute('href');
  location.href = _url;   
}

document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    var _anchor = ""; 
    if(e.target) {
        // checc which tag is clicked.
        alert("tag is :" + e.target.nodeName);

        if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
            _anchor = e.target.id;
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        } else if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
            _anchor = e.target.className;   
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        }
    }
});
```

Jsfiddle : [span-tag-working](http://jsfiddle.net/NgwS5/9/)

Comment: ok,please update me if any better code,now am accepting your answer.thanks a lot ..:)

Comment: Your update is good. I was thinking about `changeLocation(e.target.id);` - but i guess this is a matter of taste.

Comment: i like writing explicit code unless i am in hurry :). thank for pointing the mistake in the first place.

Comment: @AshishNegi : suppose if have multiple class name in span tag, above code is not working Ex:<span class="info navclas">Test</span>

Comment: @Sudheera I would recommend you to do `console.log(e.target.className) or use alert` and you would get the problem. you need to pass the `id` in the function which should be unique for e.g. It should be "info" and nothing more or less then that.

Comment: @AshishNegi,there are multiple class name in my span tag,so I can not use e.target.className, how to use id name, am not suppose to use unique id in multiple places right?

Comment: @AshishNegi,Shall I post one more question,am completely struck at the moment

Comment: You can extract the first class name from your multiple class names and use that. use `var classes = e.target.className.split(' ')` which returns an array. Its first element can be used as the id. `classes[0]`

Comment: or you can use something like your own attribute like `idtorefer` in span as `<span idtorefer="info" class="info another">` and use `getAttribute('idtorefer')` on the span div.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.className) {
        var _anchor = e.target.className;
        var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(_anchor)[1].getAttribute('href');
        location.href = _url;
    } 
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Suninsky/tZy9h/)

Comment: Thanks lot it's working ..:) sorry man i don’t have enough reputation to up vote,sure I will do in feature.

Comment: suppose if have multiple class name in span tag, above code will not work <span class="info navclas">Test</span>

Comment: Is there any other way I can do this? please suggest me Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going with class you can find the [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) and get your desired functionality

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgwS5/15/)***</kbd>

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
            var _anchor = e.target.id;
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        } else if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
            var span = e.target;
            var li = span.parentNode;
            var _anchor = li.id;   
            changeLocation(_anchor);
    }
});
```

[Same answer at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23674736/2260614)
Hope it helps....