# Javascript code for li tag child node onclick

Tags: javascript

Part of : [Javascript for li tag onclick location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669964/javascript-for-li-tag-onclick-location)

JavaScript code for li tag onclick :

Onclick issue on span tag.

Below JS working fine if i use single class name in span tag,but if use mutiple class name in SPAN tag (`<span class="info navclass">Test</span>`) onclick is not working,because "e.target.className" ponting to all class name.

Is there any way I can achieve this.

JS code :

```
var changeLocation = function(id) {
  var _url = document.getElementsByClassName(id)[1].getAttribute('href');
  location.href = _url;   
}

document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {

        if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
            var _anchor = e.target.id;
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        } else if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
            var _anchor = e.target.className;   
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        }
});
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="primaryNav fl">

 <ul id="hd_vertical" class="productNav">

    <li id="info" class="validation">
    <span class="info navclass">Test</span>
    <a class="info" href="http://validator.w3.org/">Test1</a>
    </li>

    <li id="learn" class="site">
    <span class="learn hdclass">fi</span>
    <a class="learn" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Buses</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/sudheera/NgwS5/14/

Comment: Can't you store the href/class to look for in a different attribute? Like... `data-href` or `data-linkclass` for example, and access it with `getAttribute`?

Comment: @chen I need to use onclick function right if I use getAttribute

Comment: @Cbore here I need some help on span tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than going with class you can find the [parentNode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp) and get your desired functionality

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgwS5/15/)***</kbd>

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById("hd_vertical").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
            var _anchor = e.target.id;
            changeLocation(_anchor);
        } else if(e.target.nodeName == "SPAN") {
            var span = e.target;
            var li = span.parentNode;
            var _anchor = li.id;   
            changeLocation(_anchor);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: @Sudheera have answered it also at your previous question... You can mark that as answer which might help someone...